# Symfony2 StopPropagation() on event kernel.exception fail

Tags: events, symfony, symfony-2.3

In symfony2.3, I added an eventListener on kernel.exception as a service : my listener is triggered when kernel exception occured but the StopPropagation does not stop the propagation of the event ... and so the kernel catch the event and display error page

After calling StopPropagation(), I tested the value of isPropagationStopped() : 1

> > Vn/CommonBundle/Resources/config/services.yml :

```
kernel.listener.vn.MongoCursorException:
    class: Vn\CommonBundle\Listener\VnExceptionListener
    scope: request
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

> > Vn/CommonBundle/VnExceptionListener.php :

```
public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event){
$exception = $event->getException();
    if ($exception->getCode()=='11000') {
        $attributes = (array) $event->getRequest()->attributes;
        $attributes['Mongoerror']=$exception->getCode();
        $event->getRequest()->attributes= new ParameterBag($attributes);

        $event->stopPropagation();

    }
```

Thanks by advance for your help !

Comment: are you sure that your exception-listener is actually fired before the one that displays the error page? did you try to catch the exception?

Comment: Yes my listener is the first to catch the event.
If I display a debug (ie > echo "TEST" ) just after $event->stopPropagation() : "TEST" is displayed before the error text from kernel.
If I add exit() : The error from kernel does not appear

Comment: When I catch the exception :
    try { $dm->flush(); } catch (\MongoCursorException $e) { } 
No exception appear

Comment: I actually meant catching the exception inside the listener before you stop the event propagation :)

Comment: How can I catch the exception inside the listener ?

Comment: I found this looking for a similar answer for Symfony v3.4. I'm not sure how did it work in v2, as asked here, but in v3.4 the solution for stopping the event propagation (that is - for preventing the later listeners to kick in) is to the set the response, on the current event: `$event->setResponse($someHttpResponse);`.